# windows mobile camera frozen

Tags: c#, camera, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-6

I'm developing a windows mobile 6 application that allows user to take image and send it back to server. It works fine, but sometimes, users tell me that when they press the button which opens camera dialog, it does open camera, but the they won't be able to see anything, just black. when they press and take photo, the flash will be on, and camera dialog turn frozen.
they have to restart the device into order to do it again.

any idea??

by the way i use CameraCaptureDialog.ShowDialog() to initial camera dialog and the device is Honeywell Dolphin 6000

Comment: What if you create an app to do nothing but repeatedly show the camera capture dialog. Does it work every time? If it does, then josef's idea is almost certainly correct. If not, then this is likely a driver issue and needs to be fixed by the manufacturer. (or you will need to find some work-around)

Answer (score 0):

using the camera needs a lot of resources. If your application consumes to much memory (you have a limit of 32MB per process), anything strange can happen.

I recommand to use the camera in a new process to overcome such memory limitations. Your custom app can start the second process and then watch for file changes in the pictures directory or use interprocess communication about the taken image.

See my post about virtual memory at [Slaying the memory monster](http://community.intermec.com/t5/General-Development-Developer/Slaying-the-virtual-memory-monster/m-p/16764).

Another option is to free up as much memory as possible in your app before you init and show the CameraDialog.

~regards